# How do I sort a MongoDB collection by a field in an embedded document using Mongoid?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I want to run this query using Mongoid:

```
db.users.find().sort({'users.roles.name':1})
```

What will that look like in Mongoid? Or maybe there is an easy way to have Mongoid just execute that custom query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all can you answer to the one simple question: How to sort documents by array? Yes, i also don't know..

I suppose that you can sort by specific role, using positional operator:

```
db.users.find().sort({'roles.0.name':1})
```

But i am not sure and can't test it right know and mb it's not exactly what you need. In any way you can test and come back with results, otherwise i will figure out it tomorrow.

Comment: Careless error, I did intend to sort on the first role in the collection. Thanks

Comment: Paul Elliot's answer is better.

Answer (score 4):

`User.asc("roles.name")` should do it for you.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
db.users.find().sort("{\"roles\":{\"name\":1}}");
```